# How to repeat a trigger keydown event?

Tags: jquery, click, keydown

I'm setting a little help system (step-by-step) with html and jquery. When you complete one step, if you click in the "Next" button, you can see the next step. I would like to allow user to press also the right arrow key to move forward whit the guide.
I setting the trigger to simulate the click but it works only once time.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    //function
});

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    $(".next").trigger('click'); // simulate the click on .next
  }
}); // keydown
```

Here a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/mlarsen1982/sqrx9gz7/5

Answer (score 0):

You're body element is probably getting blown away. Try adding the keydown event handler to the document instead of the body.

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    //function
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    $(".next").trigger('click'); // simulate the click on .next
  }
}); // keydown
```

Comment: Thanks Bassxzero. But the result doesn't change. The keydown works once.

Answer (score 0):

Faking key events is notoriously unreliable due to the security features of modern browsers. A more reliable solution would be to extract the logic of the `keypress` event to its own function and call it directly, for example:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
  showNext();
});

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 39) {
    showNext();
  }
});

function showNext() {
  // your logic here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rony. But the result doesn't change. The keydown works once.

Comment: Could you show a working example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net?